# drop down instead of a href

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, drop-down-menu, href

i want change this input to dropdown menu.

```
<a href="#" onclick="$('#pb1').progressBar(5);">5</a> |
<a href="#" onclick="$('#pb1').progressBar(60);">60</a> |
<a href="#" onclick="$('#pb1').progressBar(100);">100</a>
```

dropdown sample...(not work)

```
<form action="#" name="progress" onclick="$('#pb1').progressBar(10);">
   <select name="dropdown">
    <option name="radOne" value="$('#pb1').progressBar(5);" selected>5</option>
    <option name="radOne" value="$('#pb1').progressBar(60);">60</option>
    <option name="radOne" value="$('#pb1').progressBar(100);">100</option>
   </select>
</form>
```

can anyone help me about change this structure?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how you should do it.

```
   <select name="dropdown" onchange="$('#pb1').progressBar(this.value);">
    <option name="radOne" value="5" selected>5</option>
    <option name="radOne" value="60">60</option>
    <option name="radOne" value="100">100</option>
   </select>
```

Even like show, the practice of inline event handlers is not encouraged. Better approach is

```
document.getElementByid("selectboxid").onchange = function() {
    $('#pb1').progressBar(this.value);
};
```

But, since you are already using jQuery

```
$("#selectboxId").change(function() {
    $('#pb1').progressBar(this.value);
});
```

Comment: Why use plain DOM methods when you already have jQuery available?!

Comment: Because **he is already using it** (at least I don't know another js framework that uses `$('selector')`) and mixing both worlds is just ugly.

Comment: @ThiefMaster, I dont want to waste a suggestion from you, so updated :)

Comment: @ThiefMaster: Mootools uses `$('selector')` too :)